# IQueryable<T> with EntityObject using Generics & Interfaces (Possible?)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable, linqkit

I have a search repository for EntityFramework 4.0 using LinqKit with the following search function:

```
public IQueryable<T> Search<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
    where T : EntityObject
{
    return _unitOfWork.ObjectSet<T>().AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
}
```

And another class which uses the IQueryable return value to subset the query in ways that are not possible using the Boolean LinqKit PredicateBuilder expressions:

```
public IQueryable<T> SubsetByUser<T>(IQueryable<T> set, User user) 
    where T : EntityObject
{
    return set.Join(_searcher.Search<Metadatum>((o) => o.UserGUID == user.GUID),
                    arc => arc.GUID,
                    meta => meta.ElementGUID,
                    (arc, meta) => arc);
}
```

The problem here is that 'T' as EntityObject does not define GUID, so I can't use this. The natural response to this is to actually define the SubsetByUser() method to use a constraint with a GUID property:

```
public IQueryable<T> SubsetByUser<T>(IQueryable<T> set, User user) 
    where T : IHaveMetadata
{
    return set.Join(_searcher.Search<Metadatum>((o) => o.UserGUID == user.GUID),
                    arc => arc.GUID,
                    meta => meta.ElementGUID,
                    (arc, meta) => arc);
}
```

But this doesn't work. I'm using LinqKit and the Expandable() method results in:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'Oasis.DataModel.Arc' to
type 'Oasis.DataModel.Interfaces.IHaveMetadata'. LINQ to Entities only supports 
casting Entity Data Model primitive types
```

I need an IQueryable to be returned. I can do a fake like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> SubsetByUser<T>(IQueryable<T> set, User user) 
    where T : EntityObject
{
    return set.AsEnumerable()
              .Join(_searcher.Search<Metadatum>((o) => o.UserGUID == user.GUID),
                    arc => arc.GUID,
                    meta => meta.ElementGUID,
                    (arc, meta) => arc)
              .AsQueryable();
}
```

Which, of course, works, but which is also, of course, a bat-shit crazy thing to do. (The whole reason I want IQueryable is to not execute the query until we're final.

I've even tried this:

```
public IQueryable<T> SubsetByUser<T>(IQueryable<T> set, User user) 
    where T : EntityObject
{
    return set.Join(_searcher.Search<Metadatum>((o) => o.UserGUID == user.GUID),
                    arc => arc.GetType().GetProperty("GUID").GetValue(arc,null),
                    meta => meta.ElementGUID,
                    (arc, meta) => arc);
}
```

Which uses reflection to get the Runs collection– working around the compiler error. I thought that was rather clever, but it results in the LINQ exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the 
method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object, System.Object[])' method, 
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I could also try to change the search method:

```
public IQueryable<T> Search<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) 
    where T : IRunElement
{
    return _unitOfWork.ObjectSet<T>().AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
}
```

But this won't compile of course because IRunElement is not an EntityObject, and ObjectSet constrains T as a class.

The final possibility is simply making all the parameters and return values IEnumerable:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SubsetByUser<T>(IEnumerable<T> set, User user) 
    where T : EntityObject
{
    return set.Join(_searcher.Search<Metadatum>((o) => o.UserGUID == user.GUID),
                    arc => arc.GetType().GetProperty("GUID").GetValue(arc,null),
                    meta => meta.ElementGUID,
                    (arc, meta) => arc);
}
```

Which also works, but which, again, doesn't allow us to delay instantiation until the end.

So, it seems like there's little I can do to make this work without instantiating everything as an IEnumerable and then returning it using AsQueryable(). Is there some way I can put this together that I'm missing?

Comment: Would it be possible to show a little bit more code on how you used this SubsetByUser function(where you would call it from your query).  Trying to do something similar.

Comment: @AaronLS, I'm not on this project anymore, but basically– IIRC, the set argument is the returnset from another query. So it's just _subsetContainer.SubsetByUser<Widget>(_container.Search<Widget>(predicate), someUser);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The natural response to this is to actually define the SubsetByUser() method to use a constraint with a GUID property:
>
> ...
>
> But this doesn't work. I'm using LinqKit and the Expandable() method results in:
>
> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'Oasis.DataModel.Arc' to
> type 'Oasis.DataModel.Interfaces.IHaveMetadata'. LINQ to Entities only supports 
> casting Entity Data Model primitive types

You're very close with that. You can make this work if you use an `ExpressionVisitor` that removes all unnecessary casts (casts to a base type or an implemented interface) that are automatically generated.

```
public IQueryable<T> SubsetByUser<T>(IQueryable<T> set, User user) 
    where T : IHaveMetadata
{
    Expression<Func<T, Guid>> GetGUID = arc => arc.GUID;
    GetGUID = (Expression<Func<T, Guid>>)RemoveUnnecessaryConversions.Instance.Visit(GetGUID);
    return set.Join(_searcher.Search<Metadatum>((o) => o.UserGUID == user.GUID),
        GetGUID,
        meta => meta.ElementGUID,
        (arc, meta) => arc);
}

public class RemoveUnnecessaryConversions : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static readonly RemoveUnnecessaryConversions Instance = new RemoveUnnecessaryConversions();

    protected RemoveUnnecessaryConversions() { }

    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
    {
        if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert
            && node.Type.IsAssignableFrom(node.Operand.Type))
        {
            return base.Visit(node.Operand);
        }
        return base.VisitUnary(node);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, create the expression tree manually using the `Expression.*` functions, so that you can avoid including the cast in the first place.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: @hvd I think I'm trying to do something similar. Can you show an example of how you'd call SubsetByUser in a query?  I'm confused since it's not an extension method.  I'm trying to create a method that can be used by linq2entities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826275/iqueryable-extension-method-for-linq2entities

Comment: @AaronLS You'd use `from x in SubsetByUser(...) ... select x` -- it's not what you're trying to do. This is a function which returns a query. You're trying to call a function from within a query. (That said, I've since found out that my answer is needlessly complicated, and will update when I can.)

Comment: @hvd Where does SubsetByUser get declared?  In a static class? The method is not static?  I have only figured out how to use linqkit to declare a local expression variable called asOfCurrent so I can do `.Where(asOfCurrent)`.  This is a step in the right direction.  So I want to make it a little more globally available, and also be able to take a parameter(a DateTime), similar to how the above takes a User parameter.

Comment: @AaronLS It could have been a static function, except for the `_searcher` that this function uses that (as far as I can tell) is specific to this question. I'd guess that it's an instance method on the context. In your case, it could well be a static method in any class, static or nonstatic, that you want.

Comment: @hvd Errors about linq 2 entities not recognizing the method.  uusually not a problem because it'd be chained onto an AsExpandable call or with .Invoke, but can't figure out how to get it to work here, or what to pass to the `set` parameter since it's already `from x` but since it's not an extension method the first parameter is not a `this` and so doesn't automatically get the current query.