# IQueryable extension method for linq2entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to implement an extension method that will work with linq2entities.  I had initially assumed that if my extension method took and returned an IQueryable, and as long as my expression only made use of supported methods, then it would work fine.  I was having alot of trouble, so as a last resort I copied an existing .NET extension method that I knew to work(FirstOrDefault) and simply renamed it.  It would seem like it would evaluate the "cannot be translated into a store expression" validation based on the expression returned from the method, not the name of the method itself.

```
var prs = db.People.Where(p => p.PersonKey == 15).Select(p =>
  new
  {
    id = p.PersonKey,
    name1 = p.PersonHistories.AsQueryable().AsOf().Name
  } 
).ToList();
```

My extension method, which is just a copy of FirstOrDefault that I renamed:

```
public static TSource AsOf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)
{
  return source.Provider.Execute<TSource>(Expression.Call(null, ((MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()).MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(TSource) }), new Expression[] { source.Expression }));
}
```

Error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
'Models.PersonHistory AsOf[PersonHistory](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Models.PersonHistory])' 
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

How do I implement an IQueryable extension method that is supported in Linq2Entities?

What I really want AsOf(source, DateTime asOf) to do is soemthing like `source.FirstOrDefault<IHistory>(s => s.EndDate > asOf && asOf >= s.StartDate )`, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this so that it is supported by linq2entities.

**LINQKIT:** This is what I've come up with using linqkit and I'm hoping somehow I can factor this into something more reusable:

```
Expression<Func<PersonHistory, bool>> IsCurrent = (p) => p.Ends > DateTime.Now && p.Starts <= DateTime.Now;
var query = db.PersonHistories.Where(IsCurrent);
```

1. Have a more globally declared expression, instead of a local
   variable.
2. Add a DateTime asOf parameter, instead of having .Now hard coded.
3. And if possible, adapt it into an extension method(this sort of
   is the same as #1, just that an extension method is ideal.

Comment: But how would ObjectQueryProvider know how to translate your method into SQL? An Queryable extension method only hands the method over to the current query provider, which actually executes it. So you'll have to extend the query provider (if possible) or write your own on a rainy afternoon :).

Comment: Well if anyone has an example of how I could extend the query provider I'd be willing to try.  To answer your question, I assumed it would not try to translate my method(what's in a name?), but translate the expression, which it would know how to do because the expression wouldn't use anything unfamiliar to linq to entities.

Comment: Obviously I find lots of stuff by googling, but that's how I ended up wasting a day trying to get this to work only to reallize all the examples of IQueryable extensions don't work with linq2entities...  So any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [re-linq](http://relinq.codeplex.com/), which aims to escape from the `IQueryable` world and into an abstract syntax tree that's actually composable (Expressions are immutable). There's a link to a sample on CodeProject, so that can hopefully get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw you commented on my answer on another question, so i thought i'd reply here also. I've made some modifications and improvements to the code ( support for compiled queries and custom extension method to expression substitutions ).

This might serve as an answer:

```
/// <summary>
/// Type helpers
/// </summary>
internal static class TypeSystem
{
    private static Type FindIEnumerable(Type seqType)
    {
        Type type;
        if (seqType == null || seqType == typeof(string) || seqType == typeof(byte[]))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!seqType.IsArray)
            {
                if (seqType.IsGenericType)
                {
                    Type[] genericArguments = seqType.GetGenericArguments();
                    int num = 0;
                    while (num < (int)genericArguments.Length)
                    {
                        Type type1 = genericArguments[num];
                        Type[] typeArray = new Type[1];
                        typeArray[0] = type1;
                        Type type2 = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(typeArray);
                        if (!type2.IsAssignableFrom(seqType))
                        {
                            num++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            type = type2;
                            return type;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Type[] interfaces = seqType.GetInterfaces();
                if (interfaces != null && (int)interfaces.Length > 0)
                {
                    Type[] typeArray1 = interfaces;
                    int num1 = 0;
                    while (num1 < (int)typeArray1.Length)
                    {
                        Type type3 = typeArray1[num1];
                        Type type4 = TypeSystem.FindIEnumerable(type3);
                        if (type4 == null)
                        {
                            num1++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            type = type4;
                            return type;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!(seqType.BaseType != null) || !(seqType.BaseType != typeof(object)))
                {
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
                    return TypeSystem.FindIEnumerable(seqType.BaseType);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Type[] elementType = new Type[1];
                elementType[0] = seqType.GetElementType();
                return typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
            }
        }
    }

    internal static Type GetElementType(Type seqType)
    {
        Type type = TypeSystem.FindIEnumerable(seqType);
        if (type != null)
        {
            return type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
        else
        {
            return seqType;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Marks an extension as compatible for custom linq expression expansion
/// Optionally if you can not write the extension method to fit your needs, you can provide a 
/// expression id constant for a registered expression.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple= false, Inherited = false)]
class ExpandableQueryMethodAttribute :
    Attribute
{
    public ExpandableQueryMethodAttribute()
    {
    }
    public ExpandableQueryMethodAttribute(string expressionId)
    {
        _expressionId = expressionId;
    }

    private string _expressionId;
    public LambdaExpression TranslationExpression
    {
        get
        {
            return _expressionId != null ? QueryMethodTranslationExpressions.GetRegistered(_expressionId) : null;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Used to register expressions for extension method to expression substitutions
/// </summary>
static class QueryMethodTranslationExpressions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression> expressionList = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Register expression
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TFunc">type of expression delegate</typeparam>
    /// <param name="id">id constant for use with ExpandableQueryMethodAttribute</param>
    /// <param name="expr">expression</param>
    public static void RegisterExpression<TFunc>(string id, Expression<TFunc> expr)
    {
        expressionList.Add(id, expr);
    }

    public static LambdaExpression GetRegistered(string id)
    {
        //Extensions;
        return expressionList[id];
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use on object sets before using custom extension methods, except inside compiled queries
    /// </summary>
    public static IQueryable<T> AsExtendable<T>(this IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        if (source is ExtendableQuery<T>)
        {
            return (ExtendableQuery<T>)source;
        }

        return new ExtendableQueryProvider(source.Provider).CreateQuery<T>(source.Expression);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Provides PlaceHolderQuery
/// 
/// No other functionality
/// </summary>
public class PlaceHolderQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    public PlaceHolderQueryProvider()
    {
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new PlaceHolderQuery<TElement>(this, expression);
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        Type elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
        try
        {
            return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(PlaceHolderQuery<>).MakeGenericType(elementType), new object[] { this, expression });
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException tie)
        {
            throw tie.InnerException;
        }
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Does nothing
/// 
/// Acts only as a holder for expression
/// </summary>
public class PlaceHolderQuery<T> : IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
{

    private Expression _expression;
    private PlaceHolderQueryProvider _provider;

    public PlaceHolderQuery(PlaceHolderQueryProvider provider, Expression expression)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _expression = expression;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get
        {
            return _expression;
        }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get
        {
            return _provider;
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Walks the expression tree and invokes custom extension methods ( to expand them ) or substitutes them with custom expressions
/// </summary>
class ExtendableVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    class ExpandingVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> _substitutionDictionary;

        public ExpandingVisitor(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> subDict)
        {
            _substitutionDictionary = subDict;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (_substitutionDictionary != null && _substitutionDictionary.ContainsKey(node))
                return _substitutionDictionary[node];
            else
                return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }

    IQueryProvider _provider;

    internal ExtendableVisitor()
    {
        _provider = new PlaceHolderQueryProvider();
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        ExpandableQueryMethodAttribute attrib = (ExpandableQueryMethodAttribute)node.Method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ExpandableQueryMethodAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();

        if (attrib != null && node.Method.IsStatic)
        {

            if (attrib.TranslationExpression != null && attrib.TranslationExpression.Parameters.Count == node.Arguments.Count)
            {
                Dictionary<ParameterExpression, Expression> subDict = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression,Expression>();

                for (int i = 0; i < attrib.TranslationExpression.Parameters.Count; i++)
                {
                    subDict.Add(attrib.TranslationExpression.Parameters[i], node.Arguments[i]);
                }

                ExpandingVisitor expander = new ExpandingVisitor(subDict);

                Expression exp = expander.Visit(attrib.TranslationExpression.Body);

                return exp;
            }
            else if (typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(node.Method.ReturnType))
            {
                object[] args = new object[node.Arguments.Count];
                args[0] = _provider.CreateQuery(node.Arguments[0]);

                for (int i = 1; i < node.Arguments.Count; i++)
                {
                    Expression arg = node.Arguments[i];
                    args[i] = (arg.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant) ? ((ConstantExpression)arg).Value : arg;
                }

                Expression exp = ((IQueryable)node.Method.Invoke(null, args)).Expression;

                return exp;
            }
        }            

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Used for query compilation
/// 
/// If custom extension methods are used, the existing CompileQuery functions do not work, so I had to write this.
/// </summary>
static class CompiledExtendableQuery
{
    public static Func<TContext, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TResult>
      (Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TArg13, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TArg13, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TArg13, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

    public static Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TArg13, TArg14, TResult>
               Compile<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TArg13, TArg14, TResult>(
       Expression<Func<TContext, TArg0, TArg1, TArg2, TArg3, TArg4, TArg5, TArg6, TArg7, TArg8, TArg9, TArg10, TArg11, TArg12, TArg13, TArg14, TResult>> expr) where TContext : ObjectContext
    {
        return System.Data.Objects.CompiledQuery.Compile(expr.Update(new ExtendableVisitor().Visit(expr.Body), expr.Parameters));
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// The query as it becomes when AsExtendable is called on it.
/// </summary>
class ExtendableQuery<T> : IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    ExtendableQueryProvider _provider;
    Expression _expression;

    public ExtendableQuery(ExtendableQueryProvider provider, Expression expression)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _expression = expression;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _provider.ExecuteQuery<T>(_expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get {
            return typeof(T);
        }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get {
            return _expression;    
        }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get {
            return _provider;
        }
    }


}

class ExtendableQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    IQueryProvider _underlyingQueryProvider;

    private ExtendableQueryProvider()
    {
    }

    internal ExtendableQueryProvider(IQueryProvider underlyingQueryProvider)
    {
        _underlyingQueryProvider = underlyingQueryProvider;
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new ExtendableQuery<TElement>(this, expression);
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        Type elementType = TypeSystem.GetElementType(expression.Type);
        try
        {
            return (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ExtendableQuery<>).MakeGenericType(elementType), new object[] { this, expression });
        }
        catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException tie)
        {
            throw tie.InnerException;
        }
    }

    internal IEnumerable<T> ExecuteQuery<T>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _underlyingQueryProvider.CreateQuery<T>(Visit(expression)).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _underlyingQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>(Visit(expression));
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _underlyingQueryProvider.Execute(Visit(expression));
    }

    private Expression Visit(Expression exp)
    {
        ExtendableVisitor vstr = new ExtendableVisitor();
        Expression visitedExp = vstr.Visit(exp);

        return visitedExp;
    }
}
```

Sorry for the brevity of my reply, it's the middle of the night here and i've got to hurry as there is work to be done.

I'll be happy to answer any questions you might have.

Comment: Have you used this with an extension method that returns a single item, the equivilant of .First or .Single?  I was working to adapt your code to do this so that a method could provide its expression, but then I found the TranslationExpression which I think is exactly what I need.  The problem is, I don't know what to pass to register expression, since the expression I have depends on certain parameters to be present: http://pastebin.com/CpY9Sg65

Comment: P.S. This is what I have tried, but I get the error "Expression of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression' cannot be used for return type 'PropertyHistory'": http://pastebin.com/BzQWqJRY

Comment: Nevermind, I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.  this works:
`QueryMethodTranslationExpressions.RegisterExpression<Func<IQueryable<PropertyHistory>, PropertyHistory>>("1",
  source => source.FirstOrDefault(xp => xp.Ends > DateTime.Now && xp.Starts <= DateTime.Now)
);`

Answer (score 4):

This should work without extending your query provider. It basically breaks it down to exactly what your `IsCurrent` func is doing.

```
public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> IsCurrent<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
        Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> expressionEnd,
        Expression<Func<T, DateTime?>> expressionStart,
        DateTime asOf) where T : class
    {
        // Lambdas being sent in
        ParameterExpression paramEnd = expressionEnd.Parameters.Single();
        ParameterExpression paramStart = expressionStart.Parameters.Single();

        // GT Comparison
        BinaryExpression expressionGT = ExpressionGT(expressionEnd.Body, asOf);

        // LT Comparison
        BinaryExpression expressionLT = ExpressionLE(expressionStart.Body, asOf);

        query = query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expressionGT, paramEnd))
                     .Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expressionLT, paramStart));

        return query;
    }

    private static BinaryExpression ExpressionLE(Expression body, DateTime value)
    {
        return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(DateTime)));
    }

    private static BinaryExpression ExpressionGT(Expression body, DateTime value)
    {
        return Expression.GreaterThan(body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof(DateTime)));
    }
}
```

And to use it

```
var query = db.PersonHistories.IsCurrent( p => p.Ends, 
                                          p => p.Starts, 
                                          DateTime.Now );
```

Comment: This works except in places like my example(the first code block in question) where it is nested in a query, where it gives the linq2entities does not recognize method error.  The only reason LinqKit works is because they have implemented their own ExpressionVisitors, which is essentially what Gert was saying I need to do, it's just really complicated code to understand.

Comment: EF doesn't support this without tweaking your Linq parser that generates the SQL.  You can dig into the guts of LinqKit but it is a tad complicated.  I'm afraid if you want to do inline limitations on a sub-select you will need to do it in 2 steps or write it out long hand.

Comment: This may be because of EF's lineage w.r.t. Linq to SQL.  I ran into a similar problem where I ended having to repeat a complex inner query over and over because the engine simply couldn't read the obvious (to humans, at least) metadata in order to emit the correct query.

Comment: @AaronLS I see where I misunderstood the question now. But I am still confused about one thing. Isn't `p.PersonHistories` an `ICollection<PersonHistory>`? If so, why not just do `.Where(p.Ends > ...).FirstOrDefault().Name` to get the value you want?

Comment: @Steve That .Where would be repeated in multiple places, so I wanted to encapsulate that logic into an extension method.  Then the next step would be to abstract it to operate on a IHistory instead of PersonHistory, so that any object the implements IHistory could easily be sliced for a point-in-time.  I have found a solution that I think will be workable: http://pastebin.com/4fMjaCMV

Comment: @Steve Essentially what is happening is the vistior calls .Invoke on my extension method, which then returns IQueryable which replaces the extension method call in the epxresison tree.  This was what I was trying to do with LinqKit's code, but couldn't get the call to Invoke just right.  Am working at some kinks and will post the complete solution.

Comment: @AaronLS Yes, all quite a bit of work! I hope you get it. I have written a few classes which implement ExpressionVisitor, but I could not figure out how what I have done applies to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using expressions e.g.

```
Expression<Func<PersonHistory, bool>> IsCurrent = (p)
    => p.Ends > DateTime.Now && p.Starts <= DateTime.Now;

var query = db.PersonHistories.Where(IsCurrent);
```

You can define extension methods such as:

```
public static IsCurrent Func<
    IQueryable<PersonHistory>, DateTime, IQueryable<PersonHistory>
    >()
{
    return (IQueryable<PersonHistory> query, DateTime referenceDate) =>
        query.Where(p.Ends > referenceDate && p.Starts <= referenceDate);
}
```

The use it like this:

```
var query = IsCurrent();

var results = query(context.PeoplesHistory, referenceDate);
```

Or:

```
var results = query(previousResults, referenceDate);
```

Or alternatively:

```
public static IsCurrent Func<IQueryable<PersonHistory>, IQueryable<PersonHistory>>(
    DateTime referenceDate)
{
    return (IQueryable<PersonHistory> query) =>
        query.Where(p.Ends > referenceDate && p.Starts <= referenceDate);
}

var query = IsCurrent(refernceDate);

var results = query(context.PeoplesHistory);
```

That way you don't need a framework for building expressions.